# Proper Method for Implementing Getter and Setter methods for Arrays/ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

To illustrate my concern, I will use the following incomplete Test Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test
{
    private int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
    private ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public int[] getMyArray()
    {
        int[] temp = new int[myArray.length];

        for(int i = 0;i<myArray.length;++i)
        {
            temp[i] = this.myArray[i];
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getMyArrayList()
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0;i<myArrayList.size();++i)
        {
            temp.add(this.myArrayList.get(i));
        }

        return temp;
    }

    public void setMyArray(int[] newArray)
    {
        if(newArray.length!=myArray.length)
        {
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0;i<myArray.length;++i)
        {
            this.myArray[i] = newArray[i];
        }
    }

    public void setMyArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> newArrayList)
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<myArrayList.size();++i)
        {
            this.myArrayList.add(newArrayList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Is what I have illustrated with the above code the proper way to implement getter and setter methods for Arrays and ArrayLists respectively? I assume that it would be better to return copies of the Arrays and ArrayLists in the getter methods as well as set each individual element in the Array/ArrayLists in the setter methods. If this is incorrect, please illustrate the proper method for implementing these methods.

Comment: do you know there is a [copy constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) and [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) instead of doing it your self.

Comment: Also be sure to make deep copies of your elements, too if you're trying to make this class immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do, in some cases keeping it somewhat immutable is useful, which looks like what you are going for. You can write the methods a bit more concisely like so.

```
private int[] myArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
private ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public int[] getMyArray()
{
    return Arrays.copyOf(myArray, myArray.length);
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getMyArrayList()
{
    return new ArrayList<>(myArrayList);
}

public void setMyArray(int[] newArray)
{
    this.myArray =  Arrays.copyOf(newArray, newArray.length);
}

public void setMyArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> newArrayList)
{
    this.myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(newArrayList);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

there is no harm in implementing getters and setters for arrays or ArrayLists if you deem it necessary.

For arrays, there is a [copyOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) and [copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)) methods which you can use to copy an array into *a new array* rather than doing it yourself.

As for ArrayLists, there is a [*copy constructor*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) which you can use to construct a new ArrayList containing the elements of the specified collection instead of doing it yourself as well an [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) method to append all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of another list.

as for:

> I assume that it would be better to return copies of the Arrays and
>   ArrayLists

again it depends if you deem it necessary to make the array or ArrayList immutable which depend upon certain factors of what you're trying to achieve.